# R function furr::futures_map_dfr with unmatching opening bracket

Tags: r, parallel-processing, furrr

I want to process something in parallel and use

```
result_future = furrr::future_map_dfr(1:length(firmi), function(i){ #Parallel version
...
}
```

Howeverm the error tooltip says "Unmatching opening bracket '('    and it refers to the bracket after *furrr::future_map_dfr*.

When I try to close it after function(i)), the error remains and it adds unexpected tocken ')' , referring to the new closing bracket.

```
result_future = furrr::future_map_dfr(1:length(firmi), function(i)){ #Parallel version
...
}
```

What is going on?

Thanks for any help! 
M

Comment: The code in between is an optimx function.

Comment: You need a parenthesis at the end to close the call `furrr::future_map_dfr(`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes, but I tried it with a parenthesis after function(i). Then the error is 'unexpected token ')'

Comment: After the last `}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bracket has to be after the last {